# Refreshing the shown value of a list after dynamically populating it with an ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have two drop down lists - category, sub category. When I choose a category, the sub category list will update based on the category. The category id is sent through an ajax call and returns the chosen sub categories. I am also using foundation but I have been testing everything without foundation and it is essentially the same.

Initially when the page loads, the subcategories will be updated correctly. When I change to a different category, the sub categories will update correctly but the chosen text on the subcategory list will be the same text as the previously chosen value. Is there a way to refresh the shown text on a list? Or am I doing something wrong in my javascript? Also, even when there are no subcategories, the chosen value text for sub categories will be the previous text. I have tried adding a default value server side in the controller action to see if it would default to that but it does not.

My Html:

```
Subcategory: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SubcategoryId, Subcategorylist,

"--Select--", new { id = "Subcategory"})
```

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Category").on("change", function () {
        debugger;       
        ChangeSubCategories(this.value);
        $(document).foundation();
    });
    ChangeSubCategories($("#Category").val());
    $(document).foundation();

    function ChangeSubCategories(categoryID) {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action(MVC.Admin.GetSubCategories())",
            data: { categoryID: categoryID },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#Subcategory').empty();
                var options = $("#Subcategory");
                $.each(data, function () {
                    options.append($("<option />").val(this.Id).text(this.name));
                });
                $(document).foundation();
            },
        });

    }

});
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public virtual JsonResult GetSubCategories(int categoryID)
        {
            using (MultimediaEntities context = new MultimediaEntities())
            {
                var subcategories = context.Subcategories.Where(x => x.parentCategoryId == categoryID).ToList();
                Subcategory Default = new Subcategory { Id = 0, isActive = false, parentCategoryId = 0, name = "Choose Subcategory" };
                subcategories.Insert(0, Default);
                return Json(subcategories, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

The controller method returns a JsonResult with a list of items based on the chosen value of the Category List.

Comment: Are you trying to reference the element `.id` at `this.Id`?

Comment: You have not shown the relevant code, but to correctly implement cascading dropdownlist, you 2nd dropdown list needs to be populated in the controller before you pass the model to the view, not in an ajax call.

Comment: Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) for an example (in particular the code in the controller)

Comment: I apologize for not putting this in my post, I am doing so Stephen.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by _but the chosen text on the subcategory list will be the same text as the previously chosen value_. But a few points about you controller code. Do not return a collection of `Subcategories` - return only anonymous objects of what you actactually need i.e. `var subcategories = context.Subcategories.Where(x => x.parentCategoryId == categoryID).Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, name = x.name }); return Json(subcategories, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: and generate the `null` option in the script using `options.append($("<option></option>").val('').text('Choose Subcategory'));`

Comment: I see, thanks Stephen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do in the Ajax.success method is add a blank option first and then add the ones you get back from your ajax call

So basically something like this

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y77appb0/

jQuery

```
$(function() {
  var array = [{
    name: "red",
    id: 1
  }, {
    name: "green",
    id: 2
  }, {
    name: "blue",
    id: 3
  }];

    // Append a please select at the start
  $('.colours').append($("<option />").val("").text("Please select"));
  // And if you really want to set the value do this
  $('.colours').val("");
  $.each(array, function(key, value) {
    $('.colours').append(
      $("<option />").val(value.id).text(value.name)
    );
  });
});
```